# Upload file on Telegram with bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I want to send file from URL to user with Telegram Bots, My files extension in `.attheme` but I can't upload this files from Url.

Currently I can upload `.zip` , `.pdf`, but i want upload a `.attheme` file from PHP code.

This bot can upload any type of files into Telegram: [@uploadbot](http://telegram.me/uploadbot)

How can I do this ?

Comment: what kind of error do you receive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending a file by URL only works for certaining file types. If you want to upload other types of files you will have to post the file, after saving it on your own server, using multipart/form-data.

> **Sending by URL**
>  In sendDocument, sending by URL will currently only
>   work for gif, pdf and zip files. [[doc]](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files)

Sending file in PHP

```
$filepath = realpath('folder/.attheme');
$post = array('chat_id' => $GLOBALS["chat_id"],'document'=>new CurlFile($filepath));    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $GLOBALS["token"] . "/sendDocument");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Hello! I'm trying to do this with Java. I have a `.gif` file on my computer. To pass it in `sendAnimation` method I need to provide a type `InputFile`. I'm not sure how do I create that type? Telegram API says: `Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files`. Bu then, what is meant by `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: But sendDocument requires a file URL or an existing file ID or some form-data: `File to send. Pass a file_id as String to send a file that exists on the Telegram servers (recommended), pass an HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a file from the Internet, or upload a new one using multipart/form-data. `. How to upload a local file using that `multipart/form-data` thing?